# Using the PHP GD library to resize and save images is HELL

Tags: php, thumbnails, mime-types, gdlib

I'm writing a script that will upload a file from user input, resize it to a thumbnail and add the two new filenames to a database.

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get PHP to detect the image's MIME type and then give it to the header. Here is the code, I've put comments to try and make it as clear as possible:

```
        $picture = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

        /*original file location*/                  
        $file = 'picture/'.$picture.'';
        /*save thumbnail location*/
        $save = 'thumb/tn-'.$picture.'';
        /*append thumbnail filename with tn-*/
        $thumb = 'tn-'.$picture.'';
        /*get original file size*/
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
        /*get image MIME type*/
        $size = getimagesize($file);
        $fp = fopen($file, "r");
        if ($size && $fp) 
        {
        header("Content-type:".$size['mime']);
        fpassthru($fp);
        exit;
        } 
        else 
        {
        echo 'Error getting filetype.';
        }
        /*define thumbnail dimensions*/
        $modwidth = 300;
        $modheight = 200;
        /*check to see if original file is not too small*/
        if (($width > 301) || ($height > 201)) 
        {
        /*create shell for the thumbnail*/
        $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight);

        /*HERE IS WHERE I HAVE TROUBLE*/

        /*if MIME type is PNG*/
        if ($size['mime'] == "image/png")
            {
        /*try to create PNG thumbnail*/
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height);
        imagepng($tn, $save, 100); 
            }

        /*if MIME type is JPEG*/

        if ($size['mime'] == "image/jpeg")
            {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height);
        imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100); 
            }

        /*if MIME type is GIF*/

        if ($size['mime'] == "image/gif")
            {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
        imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height);
        imagegif($tn, $save, 100); 
            }
        }
        else { echo 'Your file is too small.'; }
```

So here is the part that I do not understand: the code works fine for when I upload a .jpeg, but if it is a PNG or a GIF, it brings up a page that says, 'The image '127.0.0.1:8888' cannot be displayed because it contains errors.' I'm supposing it must not have the correct Header MIME type, but could it be something else?

When I select a .jpeg, it uploads just fine to my image folder and it generates a thumbnail to my Thumbnail folder like I want it to.

But as soon as I try it with PNG and GIF, it fails. I must be missing something obvious?

Is this code any good for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I took the liberty of editing to reduce the signal to noise ratio. The very specific information doesn't help the question. I did up-vote cause I think it is an interesting question, good luck!

Comment: I have several books on PHP and am steadily learning. I do not 'insist on copy-pasting things together', that might of been an exaggeration, granted. Did you take 5 minutes to read the code and understand my problem? It's racking my brain. I love PHP but I really feel like I need the help of someone who has been at this for far longer than me.

Comment: @coreyward: I completely disagree nobody must buy and read a whole book before they are sure they even want to code in the language, he may be doing it as a hobby and may not a have a real project in mind right now, I'm all for books but only when you are determined to master a language!! After all this is a Q&A site and I thought this isn't a trivial question, in fact some effort was put into it, and might be interesting.

Comment: Thank you, Trufa. You're right, I'll cut down on the chatter next time. Maybe then I won't anger people.

Answer (score 6):

Using PHP's GD extension can truly be a pain. Personally, I would recommend adopting a abstraction library like [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/). This would simplify your code greatly:

```
$picture = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

/*original file location*/                  
$file = 'picture/'.$picture;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $picture);

/*save thumbnail location*/
$save = 'thumb/tn-'.$picture;

// Magic Begins Here ......

require "path-to/WideImage.php";

$image = WideImage::load($picture);
$thumb = $image->resizeDown(300, 200, 'inside');

$thumb->saveToFile($save);
```

Yes, all that code above reduced to four lanes.

---

A few pointers:

- Never rely on `$_FILES[]['mime']`. That's sent by the user-agent and it cannot be trusted.
- For the same reason, I wouldn't base my file names on `$_FILES[]['name']`.

Also, your original code doesn't work because you never `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, I'll look into this Widelmage magic. Also, I did use move_uploaded_file, just didn't include it because I didn't feel it was strictly necessary to understand the coding problem. 

Also, you mentioned output? Would  you mind expanding on that briefly?

And finally, I guess there are PHP functions that will allow me to detect file information on the server side? I've used getimagesize(), that sort of thing?

Comment: @Seraw: never mind, just rechecked your code... Didn't matter.

Comment: @AndrewMoore I tried using WideImage and tested it with a file and it worked. However, I applied it to my website where I load the url out of the database, but I gives me a lot of gibberish characters. Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Got better solution, hadling images can be fun actually using the [Thumbnailer](https://web.archive.org/web/20110612053114/http://freelogic.pl/thumbnailer) class.

```
function callb(& $image) {
   $image->thumbFixed(300,200)->save('/some/location/'.$image->filename);
}

// myFile refers to $_FILES['myFile']
// upload image and handle it
Thumbnailer::upload('myFile', 'callb');
```